# Trailing closure passed to parameter of type 'FormStyleConfiguration' that does not accept a closure error

Tags: swift, swiftui

im facing an issue i cant solve and when i switch form to list i get 3 other errors. and the error shows to be on the line that says Form { i tried a couple of stuff and ai but nothing is working. so if anyone can help pls do i cant pause for a long time just for this error and i cant proceed without solving it.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct DetailsView: View {
    @StateObject private var authViewModel: AuthViewModel = AuthViewModel()
    
    @State private var ageText: String = ""
    @State private var selectedCountryIndex = 0
    
        let countries = [
            "Global"
        ]
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color("BackgroundColor")
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            VStack {
                Form {
                    Section("User Details") {
                        UserDetailRowView(labelText: "Username", text: $authViewModel.currentUser?.username ?? "")
                            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                        
                        UserDetailRowView(labelText: "First Name", text: $authViewModel.currentUser?.firstName ?? "")
                            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())

                        UserDetailRowView(labelText: "Last Name", text: $authViewModel.currentUser?.lastName ?? "")
                            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())

                    }
                    
                    Section("Additional Information") {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Age:")
                                .font(.headline)
                            TextField("Enter age", text: $ageText)
                                .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                        }
                        
                        Picker("Country", selection: $selectedCountryIndex) {
                            ForEach(0..<countries.count, id: \.self) { index in
                                Text(countries[index])
                            }
                        }
                        .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
                    }
                }
                .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
                
                Button {
                    // Add code to update the user details
                } label: {
                    Text("Save")
                        .foregroundColor(Color("SecondaryColor"))
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color("HighlightColor"))
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Edit Profile")
    }
}

struct DetailsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DetailsView()
            .environmentObject(AuthViewModel())
    }
}
```

Here are the other structs:

```swift
struct UserDetailRowView: View {
    let labelText: String
    let text: Binding<String>
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(labelText)
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(Color("TertiaryColor"))
            
            TextField("Enter \(labelText)", text: text)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
        }
        .padding(.vertical, 8)
    }
}

struct User: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id: String
    let fullName: String
    let email: String
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var age: Int
    
    var initials: String {
        let formatter = PersonNameComponentsFormatter()
        if let components = formatter.personNameComponents(from: fullName) {
            formatter.style = .abbreviated
            return formatter.string(from: components)
        }
        
        return ""
    }
}

extension User {
    static var MOCK_USER = User(id: NSUUID().uuidString, fullName: "John Smith", email: "test@example.com", firstName: "Tester", lastName: "Acc", age: 16)
}
```

The class `AuthViewModel` is quite large (see comment for link to full code). It begins as follows:

```swift
@MainActor
class AuthViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var userSession: FirebaseAuth.User?
    @Published var currentUser: User?
    
    // ...
}
```

Comment: It's to do with the way you are unwrapping the optional ```User``` that is apparently a published value of ```AuthViewModel```. You are probably making things difficult for yourself by allowing the form to be launched with the possibility that ```currentUser``` is nil - it would be easier if the published value was not an optional.  For more help, please include the code for ```AuthViewModel```, ```User``` and ```UserDetailRowView```.

Comment: You didn't include `AuthViewModel`.  Please post code for that as well.  @BenzyNeez's comment is a good one.  The main issue here is that you are allowing `currentUser` to be nil.  Make it non-optional in your `AuthViewModel` and then get rid of the `?? ""`  for each place where you are trying to pass bindings to `UserDetailRowView`.  It is this expression that is ruining your life: `text: $authViewModel.currentUser?.username ?? ""`.

Comment: @BenzyNeez
user detail row view : https://code.tk.sg/acifugiwen.js
auth view model : https://code.tk.sg/uqoramewey.cs
user : https://code.tk.sg/ataloqufen.js

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for providing the additional code.

You can get it to compile by making the following changes:

1. Instead of creating the `AuthViewModel` in `DetailsView`, have it accept a `Binding` to the `User` to edit:

```swift
struct DetailsView: View {
//    @StateObject private var authViewModel: AuthViewModel = AuthViewModel()
    @Binding var currentUser: User
```

2. Change the lines that create `UserDetailRowView` to take out the handling of an optional and to refer instead to the properties of the supplied `User`. The first line in your code example is trying to bind to `User.username`, but your `User` struct does not have a `username` property, so you'll need to fix this separately.

```swift
Section("User Details") {

    // FIXME: User does not have a username property
//    UserDetailRowView(labelText: "Username", text: $currentUser.username)
//        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())

    UserDetailRowView(labelText: "First Name", text: $currentUser.firstName)
        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())

    UserDetailRowView(labelText: "Last Name", text: $currentUser.lastName)
        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
}
```

3. Supply a binding to a `User` when you create the view:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var currentUser = User.MOCK_USER

    var body: some View {
        DetailsView(currentUser: $currentUser)
    }
}
```

With these changes made, it not only compiles but even runs:

[image: Form]